# File multipage with variable page format

Tags: formatting, pagestyle

I am trying to create a file with several pages, with summary, hyperlinks, sections, etc., but that can have a variable page size, as in the "standalone" style, but with several pages.

Each page should fit the figure inserted in the page.
Each figure would have its section / subsection and a hyperlink.

Is there a document format already created for this?

Comment: Probably not. Will your "pages" be individual or take up more than one printed page? Why do you want variable page sizes and what are they; different textwidths, different textheights, different headers and footers, different ...?. Have you thought about using the `\clearpage` command?

Comment: @Peter -- I made several schemes of chemical reactions, which have different sizes. Sometimes they are wider than a standard page.
I would like to highlight the reactions, and not leave them "lost" in the middle of a page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to come up with your own solution for your problem.

The standalone style in combination with TikZ will produce a single PDF-page for each `tikzpicture` having the size of the (TikZ-)picture. Maybe this could be a start for you. You could include your figures using `node` and `includegraphics`.

This code will generate a PDF with three pages (just filled with a coloured rectangle).

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop=true,border=-3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package.

```
...
\usepackage{changepage}
...
\begin{adjustwith}{}{-8em}
wider text
\end{adjustwidth}
...
```

The two arguments lengths are added to the left and right margins respectively; positive value(s) decrease the local textwidth and negative value(s) increases it.

Comment: This will make necessary adjusta all pages with a picture, because the pictures have diferent sizes, and I have 200 pictures.